# Proving Geometry question

Tags: geometry

Prove that AF=FC

I tried to find all the angle but I'm left with two variables

Trigonometry seem too messy without using computer too.

[image]

Comment: Try to show that $\angle FAC=24^{\circ}$

Comment: Then, you're done if you can show that $\angle DCB=15^{\circ}$

Comment: @RMWGNE96 Yeah, but i don't really know how to show that.I'm assuming that i have to draw something extra to be able to solve this but i don't really know where to start.

Comment: We have $\angle DCB=15^{\circ}$ if $\angle BDF=75^{\circ}$ if $\angle ADF=105^{\circ}$ if $\angle AFD=48^{\circ}$ if $\angle AFD=2\cdot\angle FAC$.